# VMWare: connection refused

Tags: windows, putty, ssh, vmware, ubuntu

Пытаюсь соединиться по ssh (через PuTTY) с Ubuntu 10, которая крутится на виртуальной машине (VMWare Player). Сейчас выпадает сообщение - PuTTY fatal error: Connection refused. В чем может быть проблема? Я отключил фаервол в Ubuntu, не помогло. Рабочая ОС - Windows XP.

```
ip-адрес устройства (windows: свойства соединения) 192.168.60.128
ip-адрес устройства (ubuntu: ifconfig) 192.168.60.128
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, ваши ip-адреса:
1) VMware адаптеров в windows
2) Доступные ip-адреса в Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте на windows машине изменить ip-адрес на 192.168.60.2. Дело в том, что для соединения c VMWare адаптер машины, с которой заходят, должен иметь отличный ip-адрес от адаптера системы в плеере, но при этом должен находиться в той же подсети. Если это не поможет, попробуйте отключить iptables.

```
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: Аналогичная проблема была и решилась этим же способом (добавили исключение в iptables)

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install ssh-server на убунте делали? Если нет то сделайте и будет вам счастье и фаервол тут ни причем

Comment: У меня установлены ssh-server и ssh-client

Answer (score 0):

Какой тип сетевого адаптера используется?
Для доступа к виртуальной машине должен быть использован виртуальный свитч типа сетевой мост, либо Private (внутренняя сеть+хост машина).

Проверьте не от root ли вы заходите, это стандартно запрещено.