# VMWare: не коннектится

Tags: ip, vmware, putty, centos6

На тостере ответа получит не смог может быть вы сможете помочь?
Есть VMWare на ней CentOS 6 там сконфигурирован eth2 c ip 192.168.1.10
Всё это стоит на винде 7 на ней:
VMware Network Adapter VMnet1 - 192.168.238.1 / 255.255.255.0
VMware Network Adapter VMnet8 - 192.168.198.1 / 255.255.255.0

Путти ни в какую не хочет коннектится к 192.168.1.10 просто по тайм ауту заканчивает что делать? куда копать?

Comment: Включен ли файерволл? Что показывает `service iptables status`? Приложите к вопросу.

Comment: Межсетевой экран не запущен

Comment: Переставьте на VmNet1 (Bridge)

Comment: Можно чуть подробней как и что переставить?)

Comment: Вместо тысячи слов: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHHKe.png

Comment: Сделал как на скриншоте - результат такой же 
Я думаю что [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487/vmware-connection-refused) решение но не знаю где сменить IP